# Is there a foreach construct in TypeScript similar to the C# implementation?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, foreach, collections

I really like using the `foreach` construct for "for loops" in C#.  I think it's very clean, efficient and readable.

Is there a similar construct in TypeScript?  For example, instead of this:

```
setAuthorFilters(selectedAuthors)
{
    selectedAuthors.forEach(x => this.setAuthorFilter(x));
    this.updateUrl();        
}

setAuthorFilter(selectedAuthor)
{
    this.vm.SelectAuthors = this.vm.SelectAuthors.filter(x => x.id !== selectedAuthor.id);
    this.vm.PreviousSelectedAuthors = this.vm.CurrentSelectedAuthors.slice();
    this.vm.CurrentSelectedAuthors.push(selectedAuthor);
}
```

I'd like to do this:

```
setAuthorFilters(selectedAuthors)
{
    foreach(var selectedAuthor in selectedAuthors)
    {
        this.vm.SelectAuthors = this.vm.SelectAuthors.filter(x => x.id !== selectedAuthor.id);
        this.vm.PreviousSelectedAuthors = this.vm.CurrentSelectedAuthors.slice();
        this.vm.CurrentSelectedAuthors.push(selectedAuthor);
    }
    this.updateUrl();        
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the `for ... of`

E.g.

```
for(let author of authors)
{ 
  ... 
}
```

Because you're using TypeScript, this also works in IE. 
See https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/for...of.html :

> For pre ES6 targets TypeScript will generate the standard for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) kind of loop.

In plain Javascript, so without Typescript, this isn't supported in IE ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of))

Update: for scoping is `let` more similar to C# than `var`. Updated the example.

Comment: Do note that `for .. of ..` can be used with JS [Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), while the pre-ES6 translation will _not_ work with those.

Comment: @Kroltan also worth noting that the compiler has a `downlevelIteration` option that enables support even in ES3 environments.